# Short learned clauses for XSAT

Tags: reference-request, sat, resolution

Are there any studies about how effective a limited resolution pre-processor is for [DPLL-CDCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-driven_clause_learning) type SAT solvers?

By limited resolution pre-processor I mean a pre-processor that generates short (1,2, or 3 variable) resolvent clauses from a SAT instance.

I think such a pre-processor might benefit rapid restart type CDCL solvers.

I can show that connected [XSAT instances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Exactly-1_3-satisfiability) will always have numerous short resolvent clauses when the XSAT instance is converted to SAT.

This algorithm can be thought of as an inefficient [XSAT to SAT conversion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8020/1-in-k-sat-to-k-sat-reduction).

Two literals are adjacent if they appear together in a clause. A literal is always adjacent to its inverse. If a literal is true in an XSAT instance then all adjacent literals must be false.

A learned clause is created to prevent a clause from creating a conflict during the search process. We can use adjacency tables to create learned SAT clauses. Consider this unsatisfiable X3SAT example:

$(a,b,c)(a,d,e)(a,f,g)(b,d,f)(c,e,g)$

Compare the adjacency tables for the three literals in $(c,e,g)$:

$Literal | Adjacent$

$c | a, b, \bar c, e, g$

$e | a, c, d, \bar e, g$

$g | a, c, e, f, \bar g$

If one adjacent literal from each row is true then the clause will be empty causing a conflict. We can create a learned clause by choosing one literal from the adjacent column of each row, inverting them, and putting them into a SAT clause. It is best to generate unit and binary clauses first since they will subsume larger clauses. For example, $a$ is adjacent in all three rows. A conflict will occur if $a$ is true. We can create the unit learned clause $(\bar a)$.

These are SAT learned clauses that can be created from the XSAT clause $(c,e,g)$:

$(\bar a)$

$(\bar b \lor \bar c)(\bar c \lor \bar e)(\bar c \lor \bar g)(\bar d \lor \bar e)(\bar e \lor \bar g)(\bar f \lor \bar g)$

$(\bar b \lor \bar d \lor \bar f)(\bar b \lor e \lor \bar f)(\bar b \lor e \lor g)(c \lor \bar d \lor \bar f)(c \lor e \lor g)$

Applying the algorithm to the entire X3SAT instance results in this SAT instance.

$(a \lor b \lor c)(a \lor d \lor e)(a \lor f \lor g)(b \lor d \lor f)(c \lor e \lor g)$

$(\bar a)$

$(\bar b \lor \bar c)( \bar b \lor \bar d)(b \lor \bar e)( \bar b \lor e)( \bar b \lor \bar e)( \bar b \lor \bar f)(b \lor \bar g)( \bar b \lor g)( \bar b \lor \bar g)$

$(c \lor \bar d)( \bar c \lor d)( \bar c \lor \bar d)( \bar c \lor \bar e)(c \lor \bar f)( \bar c \lor f)( \bar c \lor \bar f)( \bar c \lor \bar g)$

$(\bar d \lor \bar e)( \bar d \lor \bar f)(d \lor \bar g)( \bar d \lor g)( \bar d \lor \bar g)$

$(e \lor \bar f)( \bar e \lor f)( \bar e \lor \bar f) (\bar e \lor \bar g)$

$(\bar f \lor \bar g)$

This SAT instance has a short resolution refutation:

$( \bar b \lor e) R ( \bar b \lor \bar e) \rightarrow (\bar b)$

$( \bar c \lor d) R ( \bar c \lor \bar d) \rightarrow (\bar c)$

$(a \lor b \lor c) R (\bar a) R (\bar b) R (\bar c) \rightarrow ()$

I have a more complicated algorithm that creates more learned clauses than this one.

I would also be interested in whether that are any papers about resolution refutations of XSAT instances converted to SAT.